# 2d array to two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, initialization

I got the variable 'v' which is a 2d array:

```
in = v
out = 
array([[ 217.1,  252.5],
   [  73. ,   53. ],
   [  83. ,  827. ],
   ...,
   [ 129. , 1214. ],
   [ 118.6,  908.2],
   [  90. ,   99.5]])
```

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and now I want to add this array to it in 2 seperate columns. So:

```
x        y
271.1   252.5
```

and so on.

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
df["Q_pred"],df["r_pred"] = v
```

but this gives the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I honestly don't know how to do it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's not about me or my answer but I'd like to understand: You have an attempt which doesn't work and three corrections how it would do the job: 1. make two vectors from one array and each have to be indexed (for the record: 12 characters more than your attempt) 2. add `[` and `]` 3. add `.T`. So now here comes my question:) Why is the most verbose one the accepted answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way is to index the column like this:

```
df["Q_pred"],df["r_pred"] = v[:,0], v[:,1]
```

Answer (score 7):

That's a correct idea, but you'll need the transformed matrix:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

v = np.array([[ 217.1,  252.5],
    [  73. ,   53. ],
    [  83. ,  827. ],
    [ 129. , 1214. ],
    [ 118.6,  908.2],
    [  90. ,   99.5]])

df = pd.DataFrame()

df[["Q_pred", "r_pred"]] = v.T

    Q_pred  r_pred
0   217.1   252.5
1    73.0    53.0
2    83.0   827.0
3   129.0  1214.0
4   118.6   908.2
5    90.0    99.5
```

This works with an already populated dataframe, too:

```py
df[["asdf", "qwetz"]] = v.T

    Q_pred  r_pred   asdf   qwetz
0   217.1   252.5  217.1   252.5
1    73.0    53.0   73.0    53.0
2    83.0   827.0   83.0   827.0
3   129.0  1214.0  129.0  1214.0
4   118.6   908.2  118.6   908.2
5    90.0    99.5   90.0    99.5
```

---

or shorter without transformation and in one line:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['Q_pred', 'r_pred'])

    Q_pred  r_pred
0   217.1   252.5
1    73.0    53.0
2    83.0   827.0
3   129.0  1214.0
4   118.6   908.2
5    90.0    99.5
```

Comment: Yes, one way would be to do it exactly the same (see edit). The other many ways are distributed over all the other answers (mainly @user3483203, @timgeb)

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to add multiple columns at once to an existing DataFrame.  Just assign using a list of your new columns, and convert your `numpy` array to a DataFrame:

```
df[['Q_pred', 'r_pred']] = pd.DataFrame(v)
```

```
   Q_pred  r_pred
0   217.1   252.5
1    73.0    53.0
2    83.0   827.0
3   129.0  1214.0
4   118.6   908.2
5    90.0    99.5
```